# JSOUP java.io.IOException: Input is binary and unsupported

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I have a project that requires me to use JSOUP for web scraping. I was able to get the data from the main page of the website that I want to scrape. but, as I **scrape** deeper into the page by looping into the hyperlink and accessing it, I get the following errors:

```
java.io.IOException: Input is binary and unsupported
    at org.jsoup.UncheckedIOException.<init>(UncheckedIOException.java:11)
    at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.<init>(CharacterReader.java:38)
    at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.<init>(CharacterReader.java:43)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:38)
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.initialiseParse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:65)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:46)
    at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:35)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseInputStream(DataUtil.java:169)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:835)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:285)
```

when I inspect the website, there are parts of the website that contains a commented binary data and I think it caused the problem. I've tried using this code:

```
Document docs2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.kiatravels.co.id/group_tour/index?TOUR_ID=1467&ID=15803").ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

but still didn't work.

Here's hoping some brainy code master can help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you navigated to the "Download Itinerary" link, which opens a pdf. Before parsing the link with Jsoup, you'll want to check the content-type of the url response.

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url).execute(); 
String contentType = res.contentType();
```

You'll probably want to ignore [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) that are not `text/html`.